# Преобразование символа к числу и наоборот в SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Каким образом в SQLite можно получать код символа(char to int) и преобразовывать код в символ(int to char)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sqlite> select unicode('z');
122
sqlite> select char(122);
z
```

Comment: Благодарю. Забавно, но это правда не гулится)